# How do I activate markers and link text in iBooks Author?

Tags: text, ibooks-author

I want to have text in one place/page, to tap on it and go to another place/page.

I'm new in iBooks Author, I've tried several options and I don't know how it works.

Comment: Does active mean live in the editor or active mean embedding links for eventual tapping on the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible, hopefully Apple will make the App functional in the future. You can only hyperlink to bookmarks within a project and you cant bookmark a page!

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2771):

> - Select the text you want to become a hyperlink.
> - If the Link inspector isn’t open, click Inspector in the toolbar and click the Link Inspector button.
> - In the Link inspector, click Hyperlink.
> - Select “Enable as a hyperlink.”